# c# passing data between pages

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

```
DataReader r = DataReader.FromBuffer(result.Value);
Byte[] b = new byte[result.Value.Length];
r.ReadBytes(b);
String s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(b);

String[] vals = s.Split(';');
String o = "X=" + vals[0] + "  Y=" + vals[1] + "  Z=" + vals[2];
```

I have created this code in page 'Scenario2_Client'. Now I created another page named 'Scenario3_Exercise'. How do I pass the value over from one page to another ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

make a class which is accessible to both (usually in same project)

```
public class CommonData
{
    public static string o = string.Empty;
    public static void SetData(string s)
    {
        String[] vals = s.Split(';');
        o = "X=" + vals[0] + "  Y=" + vals[1] + "  Z=" + vals[2];
    }
}
```

so in `Scenario2_Client` where you have written that code, instead of doing that, you can call this classes method and pass string `s` in that method.

```
CommonData.SetData(s);
```

this will set value of string `o` with proper string containing values of `x`,`y`, and `z` . and in `Scenario3_Exercise` where you need this string fetch it from this class's static memebr

```
string dataInScenario3_Exercise = CommonData.o;
```

Comment: ...and forget about extensability and testability

Comment: @vasily.sib can you please explain a little how this will affect extensability and testability of application ? as i have seen this approach in a project which is enhancing it self day by day. and they are performing unit test easily as overall logic is modular.

Comment: interesting, let me try. :)

Comment: @Amit, you just can't mock this method when testing, and your pages now are closely tied with this `CommonData` class. Now, when you change something in your page, you need to remember, that this may affect your CommonData class, and when you change your CommonData - don't forget to check all of your pages

Comment: @vasily.sib I think, I got your point what you are saying. Don't take `CommonData` as bound with forms, usually in well established project this `CommonData` should not be directly accessible to forms but through `Controller` or `Model` (in MVC) or `Model` (in MVVM - common data will act like Repository class). but here I've kept it simpler for beginner level. it will be acually beneficial as logic of spliting string `s` is decoupled and put in one place.. any changes in such logic will be done once and reflected in all places.

Comment: @Amit, you just show this beginners a 'static-methods-cheat':) Now, any time, when they need to make an interaction between 2 objects, they will just use this 'static-method-approach'. More then that, this static code isn't thread-safe. So, if I were you, I would add a bold line **"DO NOT abuse this approach, because it's bad"** to the answer.

Comment: @vasily.sib brother using `Static` is not bad practice! we just need to how it works and how it can be beneficial to our purpose and what things we should keep in our mind.  In his question OP have not mentioned if he is doing multiple threading or not. all i could got from the question there is a data which should be same for both form. In fact .Net has used static a lot internally (where it is best suitable) - All methods which we call from Type. In short all members and functions which are not  object specific can be used as static.

Comment: @Amit, exactly, all members and functions which are not object specific can be used as static. However, `CommonData.SetData()` method is specific for `CommonData.o` field

Comment: and `CommonData.o` is also static and will be same for both Forms (and  all possible objects of `CommonData` - if any). If `o` was not static and can be different for different object of `CommonData`, static method `SetData()` should not be setting it.